# A question I asked on unix.SE was migrated to SO, but it was about targeting UNIX/Linux in particular, not algorithms or the like generally speaking

Tags: discussion, support, migration, scope

The question in question was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804383/getting-started-writing-a-concurrent-application-on-linux-unix

It *is* about software development, but it will categorically never need to target for example Windows, so ***I*** think unix.SE is a far more on-topic location for it (but if I'm wrong, please do let me know!).

This may be why it hasn't received any answers, despite being open (as of writing this) for 6 days.

Comment: From [Unix and Linux's help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on Stack Overflow."

Comment: Ah, thanks. My mistake, TIL!

Comment: Hm, I see the question was closed on Stack Overflow. It might be a better fit for Programmers, but I'm not entirely sure. I've [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18659356#18659356) the site's regulars, and I'm sure we'll get some feedback soon enough. You might be interested in joining us in our chat room, even if the question doesn't fit as is, we could probably help you make it a bit more specific.

Comment: Shouldn't _this_ question be migrated to meta.unix-SE?

Answer (score 4):

As [Yannis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162704/yannis) pointed out in a comment, Unix & Linux Stack Exchange [specifically excludes non-shell-script programming questions in its scope](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Hence, the question being migrated to Stack Overflow was very likely the correct course of action. (And had you looked specifically at the site's scope before asking, you would likely have seen that it should have been asked on Stack Overflow to begin with.)

For **algorithm** questions, many times (but not all) the correct site to head for is the [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which lists as on-topic:

> - algorithm and data structure concepts

Answer (score 1):

[Your question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/263141/53019) has been migrated to Programmers, and I've edited the question to narrow the scope.

Part of the challenge with your original question was that it was overly broad.  That breadth made it difficult to fit your question within a particular site.

One of the bigger aspects that I edited out of your question was the re-use and portability aspects.  While it's nice to try and find a more general solution to a problem, sometimes the problem at hand is more than enough to tackle.

I also tried to summarize the two approaches you were considering, which boiled down to using two processes or a single process with multiple threads.  In order to help keep the question from getting closed (again) as too-broad, I provided some suggested approaches within your question.

That said, I maintained your original constraints regarding time-to-completion and limited hardware resources.

One thing I wasn't able to add in but would help garner you better answers is if you specified what language you are using.  I'm using it's C based upon your system calls to `fork()` and `pipe()` but I didn't want to add that in without confirmation.